# Relay: fetch for recursive data returns null

Tags: javascript, recursion, reactjs, relayjs, graphql

I have a recursive data structure to be fetched and displayed. I have a graph ql type as follow:

```
human {
  name,
  children: [human]
}
```

Now I wanted to incrementally fetch data and hence used to react classes HumanList and HumanItem, where I've used relay to fetch children only when a item is clicked. In my actual code relay gives children a null on very click i.e. on rendering very first set of children. I tried test code on relay playground and found similar issue. [Here](https://gist.github.com/shahankit/409c8640b01f1d910fb0) is the link to gist. Playground.js contains the code part and Playground.gql.js contains schema part. Clicking on each number open children under it. After 3 or 4 level it starts showing `Found children as null`. For me it happens on `1.1.2.2`. If it doesn't happens so for you then try adding more levels in SCHEMA code and the bug would pop in.

I've already checked relay issues [#246](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/246) and [#536](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/536) but none of them helped.

Any help is very much welcome.

Comment: I made a Relay Playground from the gist - just copy-pasting the code and schema files - and it works exactly as expected, with children expanding when the parent name is clicked. Could you could link directly to a broken playground? It would help to debug.

Comment: @JoeSavona In relay playground keep clicking on each number till you end up way down and you will find message Found children as null. Actually that message is the error. If you check the graphql code and check the hierarchy then you'll find that there are more children even below. If you still cannot manage to track the error then try increasing the children in graphql code and it will fail. It happened same for me initially worked till level 2 but then failed further.

Comment: @JoeSavona I updated the gist and question to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug. Given a plural field, when the time came to make a query for new data, we would diff what we have in the store with what the application wants. The bug was that we would assume that *all* records of a plural field have the same shape in the store, and only use the first store record in any plural field against which to diff. This was of course not true in your case, where some records in a plural field might be expanded and some might be collapsed.

This has been fixed as part of https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1243 and will be released in the version after Relay 0.9.1.